# cant add reference to asp.net C# web application

Tags: asp.net, dll

cant add reference to asp.net c# web application

1. im working on  visual studio 2010 and .net ver 2
2. im adding a normal dll such as ajaxcontroltoolkit or sqlserversmo and ...

when i add reference to my project get this prompt

could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

after many search i try the TLIMB.exe and STrongname but get this error 
my.dll is not a valid type of library

Comment: Exactly how did you add it?

Comment: i add my reference  project>reference  >add reference  and browse my dll to add

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the underlying COM component (ie: SQL Server SMO) wrapped in the NET assembly you're trying to add isn't registered. Try reinstalling it first.

Other simpler idea: are you running VS as admin?

Comment: yes   vs as admin ,i fix  that with user built dll in same machine